# Is there away to make popups that open when you click different parts of an SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, svg, popup

Is there a way to have popups (not a completely different page) open when you click different parts of an SVG?

I know that if you add to an SVG element a link you can do it like this:

```
<a xlink:href="google.com" >
    <rect x="341.2" y="375.5" class="st48" width="321" height="207.4"/>
</a>
```

And you can have a popup contained in a div element.

Would attaching a popup link within an svg element be similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are many ways you could do this. You could easily set an `onclick` function for any part of the svg (any node within the `svg` tag) using `document.querySelector('svg [part])` (check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp) for the correct CSS combinators for your use case).

[Here is a quick example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/_SUM1_/x6vu703a/16/).

If you wanted to be even more intricate, you could create a transparent shape over any part of your SVG to serve as your `onclick` area.